# What is the best way to add gradient to many complex shapes?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, information-graphics

I'm trying to replicate a color sales exhibit that we use for a specific client, the software that was previously used is no longer supported by AutoCAD, and we are trying to find a solution. I've been trying to use Illustrator/Photoshop to get the desired results, but I'm having trouble finding an efficient way to get the results that are desired by the client. The previous program was able to use a paint bucket style fill with a preset gradient that would automatically generate to the shape of the lots. Obviously, Illustrator and Photoshop's gradient tool does not work like this. I've been able to use the pen tool to get a similar result, but I've found that it isn't very efficient and can be quite sensitive when you are clicking along the lines/curves to trace the lots. This has led to me spending about a minute or two at least, to get the desired look of the lot. Now, when I have anywhere up to 500 some odd lots in a subdivision to color and get the look right, this time really adds up. So, I was wondering if there was a more timely solution or an alternative way of getting the correct look. Thanks!

[image: Color Sales Exhibit Example]

[image: Results with Illustrator]

Answer (score 2):

For **Illustrator** use [**Graphic Styles**](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/graphic-styles.html).

Create the appearance for one object, drag it to the Graphic Styles Panel. Then select other object and click the Graphic style you just created.

[image]

You can change/update a Graphic Style by altering the appearance and then holding the <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> key down and dragging the object on top of the style in the Graphic Styles Panel. All objects with *that* style applied will update to reflect the new appearance.

[image]

Or mix and match, by creating multiple styles...

[image]

<sub>(Horribly ugly gradients here to keep gif file sizes to a minimum.)</sub>

---

Be aware, I've outlined how to apply gradients to multiple object above. **However**, your sample of the original image is *not* using simple gradients. They are contoured highlights which are *specifically* shaped to match the overall object shape.

Another option, which can also utilize **Graphic Styles** *and* create the contoured highlight appearance, is to create an appearance using two fills and some alterations to one of the fills....

[image]

Again, drag the object to the **Graphic Styles** panel and you can apply the stacked fill appearance to multiple objects.